# Split a Key Value Pair, Give Them New Keys

Tags: javascript, json, split, key

Currently, my JSON looks like this:

```
var json = {"level" : [
                {"hs": 20},    //one
                {"no_hs": 30}  //two 
            ]};
```

I need it to look like this:

```
var json = {"level" : [
               {"education" : "hs", "amount" : 20},   //one
               {"education" : "no_hs", "amount" : 30} //two
]};
```

How do I split a key value pair, make both values, and then add keys to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting the keys.

```js
var object = { "level": [{ "hs": 20 }, { "no_hs": 30 }] };

object.level = object.level.map(function (a) {
    var o = {};
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        o.education = k;
        o.amount = a[k];
    });
    return o;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(obj)` to return an array of keys for a given object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Then you access the first key using `[0]`, because your object only has one key-value pair.

```js
var json = {"level" : [
                {"hs": 20},    //one
                {"no_hs": 30}  //two 
            ]};

var ret = [];

json.level.forEach(function (item) {
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    ret.push({
      education: Object.keys(item)[0],
      amount: item[key]
     });
  });

json.level = ret;

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(json, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to do it...
Resolved with 1 map function...
For each element in the level array, get the first key of the object and return the new element.

```
var json = {"level" : [
            {"hs": 20},    //one
            {"no_hs": 30}  //two 
        ]};

json.level = json.level.map(function(val) {
    var key = Object.keys(val)[0];
        return {
            education: key,
            amount: val[key]
        };
    });
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!